# Firestoreでdocumentが存在するか確認する方法は？

Tags: firebase, kotlin

Firestoreでdocumentが存在するか確認する方法を教えてください。

言語はKotolinです。

Answer (score 1):

[DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#exists)の `exists()` から確認できます。Documentが存在しない場合には `getData()` などを用いてもnullが返されるので、それから判断することも可能です。

> If the DocumentSnapshot points to a non-existing document, getData() and its corresponding methods will return null. You can always explicitly check for a document's existence by calling exists().

```kotlin
val docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")
docRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (!document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
            }
            ...
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            ...
        }
}
```